# How to force the script to be executed in specific place?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, igoogle

I have the following script :

```
<script type="text/javascript"src = "//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/100080069921643878012/facebook.xml&amp;up_useNewFB_p=1&amp;up_showPopUp2_p=true&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=500&amp;title=Facebook&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

to use the igoogle gadget .

---

I execute this script in run time through the following code :

```
HtmlGenericControl div_general_ac = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"");
str.Append("src = '" + dt_list.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Field<string>("process_url") + "'" + "></");
str.Append("script>");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "rowTest", str.ToString());
return div_general_ac;
```

---

Everything goes okay. The gadget is created but not in `div_general_ac`.  I want to execute the script in the div.

---

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx):

> The main difference is that the RegisterStartupScript method places
>   the JavaScript at the bottom of the ASP.NET page right before the
>   closing  element. The RegisterClientScriptBlock method places
>   the JavaScript directly after the opening  element in the page.

I want the script in specific place not in the top or the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use ClientScript. If all you are after is putting the script into the `<div>` element, then just put it there.  Example:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.Controls.Add(CreateGadget());
    }


    private HtmlGenericControl CreateGadget()
    {
        HtmlGenericControl div_general_ac = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"");
        str.Append(" src = '" + dt_list.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Field<string>("process_url")+ "'></");
        str.Append("script>");
        div_general_ac.InnerHtml = str.ToString();
        return div_general_ac;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

use these:

```
  HtmlGenericControl div_general_ac = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"/>");
    str.Append("document.getElementById('idDiv').innerHTML = '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src = '" + dt_list.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Field<string>("process_url") + "'" + " />';");
    str.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "rowTest", str.ToString());
    return div_general_ac;
```